# How to run Angular 2 apps with Node on Ubuntu?

Tags: npm

I am trying to install the Angular CLI on Ubnutu 17.04 with via

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

However it generates the following warnings:

```
    npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /usr/local/bin/ng as it wasn't installed by /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

and once completed, although the `ng` executable is in my path, if I try to run any command (e.g. `npm serve`) I am given the following:

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

It appears to have (attempted?) to install Angular CLI 1.3.2 but the command `ng --version` doesn't even run. (Produces the error above). As a result I cannot run npm start for Angular 2 apps that I am building.

My npm version is 5.3.0, nodejs version is v4.7.2. I have tried many times now to get this to work and I'm starting to think that maybe there's a bug  in npm or angular CLI because I've been successful at installing the Angular CLI on both Mac, Windows and ArchLinux on the command line. How can I get npm to run angular apps on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
sudo su
```

check the version of `node` and `npm`

> Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by
>   running `node -v` and `npm -v` in a terminal/console window. Older
>   versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine.

then use

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

create new folder

```
ng new my-dream-app
```

change the current directory to the newly created folder

```
cd my-dream-app
```

start the angular server with

```
ng serve
```

I recommend you to use 16.04 lts ubuntu verion

Answer (score 0):

That version (1.3.x) for Angular CLI needs Node 6.9 or higher (read from @angular/cli from npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/1.3.0).

I suggest you to install node version manager (NVM) in order to manage different node versions, docs [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation)

After getting the proper node version installed, try again to install angular cli and it should work fine.